# Define a custom method in Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm fetching data with a many-to-many relationship and I want to define acustom method. Is it possible (and how) to use something like:

```
$hotel = $entityManager->getRepository('Hotels')->findOneById(1);
$types = $hotel->getTypes(); //$types is instance of **Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection**
$types->myCustomFunction(); //do something
```

Comment: I don't want to use repository, becouse i need to work with many to many relationship only. I want to create something like `$hotel->getTypes()->fetchPairs()`

Comment: sorry, i misread the question, you may want to checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691943/custom-collection-in-doctrine2 though

Comment: Thank, I tried it, but this doesn't solve my problem. I need to call custom method on object which is instance of Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection (that i've got when I fetch many to many relationship).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be not implemented already.

See this Doctrine's JIRA issue : http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-547

> ## Consider allowing custom PersistentCollection implementations
>
> We should consider allowing the configuration of custom PersistentCollection implementations on a per-association basis.
>   This could allow users to craft optimized (SQL) behavior for for some of their collections to improve performance without changing the domain model code.
>
> For this, PersistentCollection needs to be designed for inheritance.