# Configure per-repository collection in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Given the following collection:

```
class ProductsCollection extends ArrayCollection
{
    // ...
}
```

And the following entity:

```
class Invoice
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="invoice")
     */
    protected $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ProductsCollection();
    }
}
```

When Doctrine hydrates the invoice products, it does it with the default collection class. I've read [in the docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/configuration.html#configure-collection-class) that it is possible to change this collection class globally.

Is it possible to configure it per repository?

Thanks!

Edit:

After a bit more research, it seems it is still NOT possible. See

- [Custom Collection in Doctrine2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691943/custom-collection-in-doctrine2)
- http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-547

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that the link you provided is from the documentation for `doctrine1` ? But never mind - changing the collection  class is possible in `doctrine2` aswell :)

Comment: The `PersistentCollection` being talked about in the JIRA issue differs from an `ArrayCollection`.

Comment: @nifr yes, but it doesn't change the fact that the collection is not customizable, right?

Comment: Hm it should be possible using a `postLoad` listener. What's your exact use-case that can't be solved with a few custom methods in the repository or little helpers in the entity itself? What do you plan to put in that custom collection?

Comment: I want to refactor the entity by moving some methods to the custom collection. I could move it to a helper class instead, but the collection fits better in my opinion. The postLoad method is an option, thankyou! I'm a bit concerned of performance issues when loading many entities. But it's the best approach for now. The other is to "cast" the PersistentCollection to a CustomCollection in the methods involved.